# Ammap lines Simulation from external JSON file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, amcharts

I am trying to insert external JSON data to my ammap using dataLoader and use those datas to animate the lines on the postProcess in the ammap map

```
 var map = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "map",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataLoader": {
        "url": "/directory_to_json_file/json_file.json",
        "postProcess": function(data) {
            var dataProvider = {
                "map": "worldLow"
            };
        }
    },
...
}
```

i want to insert the json file after loading worldLow map and add lines latitude and longitude and animations from the external json file.

json_file

```
{
 map: "worldLow",
  getAreasFromMap: true,
  linkToObject: "london",
  images: [{
    id: "london",
    color: "#000000",
    type: "circle",
    title: "London",
    latitude: 51.5002,
    longitude: -0.1262,
    scale: 1.5,
    zoomLevel: 1.74,
    lines: [{
      latitudes: [51.5002, 37.483577],
      longitudes: [-0.1262, -89.824219]
    }]
  },
    {
      svgPath: pcSVG,
      title: "London",
      latitude: 51.5002,
      longitude: -0.1262
    },
    {
      svgPath: pcSVG,
      title: "Prague",
      latitude: 37.483577,
      longitude: -89.824219
    }

  ]
}
```

it alerts error.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. All property names must be in double quotes, e.g `{ "map": "worldLow" }`

Comment: I did change the Property in double quotes, but not working still

Comment: Can you edit the actual error you're getting into your question?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to quoting your properties, you can't pass variables into your JSON. You need to expand the instances of `pcSVG` the SVG string the variable represents. Using the target SVG from the [animation across lines demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animations-along-lines/):

```
{
        "map": "worldLow",
        "getAreasFromMap": true,
        "linkToObject": "london",
        "images": [{
                "id": "london",
                "color": "#000000",
                "type": "circle",
                "title": "London",
                "latitude": 51.5002,
                "longitude": -0.1262,
                "scale": 1.5,
                "zoomLevel": 1.74,
                "lines": [{
                        "latitudes": [51.5002, 37.483577],
                        "longitudes": [-0.1262, -89.824219]
                }]
        }, {
                "svgPath": "M9,0C4.029,0,0,4.029,0,9s4.029,9,9,9s9-4.029,9-9S13.971,0,9,0z M9,15.93 c-3.83,0-6.93-3.1-6.93-6.93S5.17,2.07,9,2.07s6.93,3.1,6.93,6.93S12.83,15.93,9,15.93 M12.5,9c0,1.933-1.567,3.5-3.5,3.5S5.5,10.933,5.5,9S7.067,5.5,9,5.5 S12.5,7.067,12.5,9z",
                "title": "London",
                "latitude": 51.5002,
                "longitude": -0.1262
        }, {
                "svgPath": "M9,0C4.029,0,0,4.029,0,9s4.029,9,9,9s9-4.029,9-9S13.971,0,9,0z M9,15.93 c-3.83,0-6.93-3.1-6.93-6.93S5.17,2.07,9,2.07s6.93,3.1,6.93,6.93S12.83,15.93,9,15.93 M12.5,9c0,1.933-1.567,3.5-3.5,3.5S5.5,10.933,5.5,9S7.067,5.5,9,5.5 S12.5,7.067,12.5,9z",
                "title": "Prague",
                "latitude": 37.483577,
                "longitude": -89.824219
        }]
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/a439193d27612909dbcb8ba6e13577d7?editors=1010)

Also note that you don't need the `postProcess` callback if you're returning the correct map dataProvider object. `postProcess` is only needed if you're returning something that isn't compatible and need to convert your data into something the map library understands, so your `postProcess` call is unnecessary.